# What is the use of spread syntax in function while creating a new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

I understand about JavaScript spread syntax in general. But in the following code, I cannot understand why it is used when creating a new array of specific length:

```
const createArray = length => [...Array(length)];
```

Comment: Have you tried comparing the result with e.g. `length => Array(length)`? It should quickly become obvious why you generally don't want that.

Comment: @VLAZ yes, it does. It has all the explanations I needed. Thanks a lot to you and other members. Happy coding to all.